# Can't read file content when using others browsers excepts IE

Tags: c#, .net, io

When i try this code using IE i can read the content of the file because IE gives the full path oh the file.

```
       void SaveBranchDetails()
        {
           string fileLocation = AsyncFileUploadBranch.PostedFile.FileName;
           try
           {
             BranchData b = new BranchData();
             StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileLocation);
             var result = CSV.ReadingCSVFile<BranchData>(sr);
              foreach (var rec in result)
              {
                //get details
                  b.Id = rec.Id;
                  b.Branch = rec.Branch;
                  b.Active = rec.Active;
                  b.SaveBranches();
              }
              sr.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }

    }
```

Using  the others browsers to perform the same task give me an error:

```
  Could not find file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\branches.csv'.
```

At the following line :

```
 StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileLocation);
```

How can i fix this problem ?

Comment: what is `AsyncFileUploadBranch`? where is this code running? on client? on server? where does the browser fit in this code? i cant see any reference to IE.

Comment: @inquisitive AsyncFileUploadBranch is the name of the AsyncFileUpload. when i upload the file using IE i can read the content of the file but using another browser i can't read the content and i posted the error and the line that causes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [`FileContent`](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/ajaxcontroltoolkitsamplesite/asyncfileupload/asyncfileupload.aspx) property because that is the Stream of bytes that is returned from the browser.

If you change your code as follows I expect it to work for all browsers:

```
 BranchData b = new BranchData();
 using(var sr = new StreamReader(AsyncFileUploadBranch.FileContent))
 {
     using (var csvReader = new CsvReader(sr))
     {
         var result = csvReader.GetRecords<BranchData>().ToArray();
         foreach (var rec in result)
         {
            //get details
            b.Id = rec.Id;
            b.Branch = rec.Branch;
            b.Active = rec.Active;
            b.SaveBranches();
         }
     }
 }
```

If that doesn't work you might also try `AsyncFileUploadBranch.PostedFile.InputStream` instead.

Comment: `CSV.ReadingCSVFile<BranchData>(streamreader sr);` uses streamreader as input not inputstream or file content. @rene

Comment: i tried it but having this error `You must call read on the reader before accessing its data.` at the following lines `var result = CSV.ReadingCSVFile<BranchData>(sr);`

Comment: i need to read the data from a csv file with the following data (id, branch,active). BranchData is a class that has the proprieties and method to save the read data from the csv file.

Comment: i solved the problem by looking at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11086942/using-csvhelper-on-file-upload